# Errors using input-only web service (OUT_ONLY from ESB)

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a webservice with some input only operations. In the ESB i've created a proxy and sets the properties `OUT_ONLY and FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED` to true. Everytime I call the proxied operation I get the following error message in the wso2carbon.log:

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-04-02 09:52:45,307] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool} -  Uncaught exception {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool}
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not yet implemented
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperation.getMessage(OutOnlyAxisOperation.java:124)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.processResponse(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:125)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.receive(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:81)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Althought everything seems to work OK, I am worried about this message. What am I doing wrong. These input only will be called very frequently in production, so I'd like them to be error free.

```
WSO2 ESB: 4.8.1
```

Thanks,

Danny

Comment: I can see processResponse in the stack trace : are you sure that your webservice return nothing ? Try with tcpmon between the esb and your webservice : perhaps can't you call the webservice from the ESB (and therefore you receive a response from a firewall or a kind of 404...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue for now: My ESB was running in multi-tenant mode. The proxy service were created in the tenant. I did a fresh install and put the config in (so no tenants). The error disappears immediately. When I remove the config and create a tenant and put the config into the tenant the error reappears. So might this be a bug. I can try to verify with running sample 253 (OneWayProxy) in a tenant.

Answer (score 0):

this exception will occur if OUT_ONLY=true and your backend sending a response back to the esb.if OUT_ONLY is set true, your are getting a response from the backend then it is not a valid scenarion for if OUT_ONLY property.check this post[1]

1.https://mohanadarshan.wordpress.com/2013/05/05/out_only-scenario-in-proxy-service-wso2-esb/

Comment: OK. I've read the post. But what is the correct way of handling a soap call with only an input message? What should the service return and how do I handle this correctly in the ESB.

Answer (score 0):

Out-only property is set to inform that this service does not return a response back. For instance if you are sending messages to a message broker. Force-sc-accepted flag causes ESB to send HTTP Accepted status response back to the client (which calls ESB) since otherwise client will timeout without a reaponse. So please make sure your backend service does not send a response and it is accessible to ESB.