# OUT_ONLY Issue on Multi-Tenant Mode (WSO2 ESB 5.0 BETA)

Tags: multi-tenant, wso2-esb

I'm experiencing the following issue when in Multi-Tenant mode on the WSO2 ESB 5.0 Beta version. This occurs when I send to an endpoint(which is a webservice running on WSO2 AS 5.3). I've tried changing the method on the Webservice, both to return a value and to return nothing(i.e. a void method) with no luck. Everything seems to process fine, except the following error seems to appear on my log file, exactly 3 minutes, after the message was sent.

Issue similar to

[[Errors using input-only web service (OUT_ONLY from ESB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407871/errors-using-input-only-web-service-out-only-from-esb/38502112#38502112)  ][1]

I also think this may be related to bug 'ESBJAVA-3989' - "Exception thrown when OUT_ONLY is set and a response is received for an API in Tenant Mode", however I see no anticipated fix for it. My rationale of moving to ESB 5.0 was to maximize the Multi-tenant features, which had few bugs in the previous versions. However, this is proving to be a stumbling block.

Any ideas ?

```
     TID: [-1] [] [2016-07-21 15:04:06,810] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool} -  Uncaught exception {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool}
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not yet implemented
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperation.getMessage(OutOnlyAxisOperation.java:124)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.processResponse(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:140)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.receive(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:82)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:255)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug identified in ESB tenant mode and reported in jira [1]. Still team did not fixed that and will do according to the priority.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3989

Comment: Thanks Dilshani for the update. Any idea if the fix will be applied to the final ESB 5.0 release, or will it be applied to a later release i.e.(5.1). This does seem to be affecting all messages going out to external services, when in Multi-Tenant mode, so we might have to delay our implementation of the later ESB until this has been resolved.

Comment: ESB 5.0 is going to release soon and this issue not going to solve within this release. It will be going to address through future releases. If you need this functionality immediately, you can require support from WSO2 team for that. WSO2 team will arrange necessary.